# Should we name names when talking about bad publishers and researchers?

Tags: discussion

In this question: [My paper was withdrawn from predatory journal after publication, what should I do?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/29991/my-paper-was-withdrawn-from-predatory-journal-after-publication-what-should-i-d) the OP is considering naming the publisher and a high rep user has recommended them to do this. I personally do not think naming the publisher adds any value and I do not want AC.SE to be a place to list bad publishers and researchers. If naming the publisher, journal, or researcher adds value to a question or answer, then I think it is important to name names. In cases where naming names is simply to shame publishers/people, I think it is a bad idea.

Comment: This question may help: [What is the website policy on naming brands in questions/answers?](http://meta.academia.stackexchange.com/questions/1184/what-is-the-website-policy-on-naming-brands-in-questions-answers)

Comment: Another note is that we have no guarantee that the information is accurate. A few weeks ago on Stack Overflow, I got a review where the person's first post said he had personally worked with the author cited in the question and called him an idiot. We can't determine intent or truth in a question. If a person is doing wrong, then official channels are the ones that will ultimately solve the problem.

Comment: Dear Mods: I am so pleased with your moderation of Academia.SE. You are all very professional, prompt, and diplomatic. Now there's the fact that 3/4 of you participated in this _proactive_ discussion, which puts you over the top in my books. Keep up the excellent work :).

Answer (score 25):

I think that, while naming *people* is inappropriate and not constructive (example: grad student complaining about their supervisor Prof. Doe to be a mean, mean person), *publishers* are another story.

As commercial operations, they accept to be public entities and it's practical to the community to be able to discuss about a specific company (see for example this: [Do Springer, IEEE, Elsevier charge a fee for non-open-access journals?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/18625/10643)), the same way we discuss the pros and cons of, say, a reference manager software. For example, there are several questions about Elsevier's editorial website (example: [How can co-authors check the status of a submitted manuscript in Elsevier Editorial System?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/20834/10643)).

The same holds for universities. Why put universities under scrutiny ([What is the status/reputation of the University of South Africa (UNISA)?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/10728/10643)) but not publishers?

Additionally, if a scholar is wondering about a given publisher, chances are the query will be more along the line of: [Is Lambert Academic Publishing a reputable company?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/2513/10643) or [Is MDPI a reputable Academic Publisher?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/5466/10643) than 'What is the process to evaluate the shadyness of a given publisher'.

There are also multiple comments and answers that are critical about the business model of established publishers and I think it's very well, but we should also be able to openly criticize the smaller, less experienced, and especially the dishonest ones.

Answer (score 14):

I agree that there is no benefit to naming names, and it can be detrimental to do so.

Besides, if a question requires the name of the publisher in order to be answered, it's probably too localized, anyways (as per our [help center](https://academia.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) guidelines). A better approach is to give details that *characterize* the publisher (as Kurt did quite well). This ensures that the question and answers will be applicable not just in this one situation, but also others like it.

Comment: Should a question like this one: http://academia.stackexchange.com/q/2513/10643 be deleted or flagged?

Comment: @CapeCode I think in that case naming the publisher is critical to the question. As for whether it is a good question for the site the up votes suggest the community likes it and I tend to agree, although I would not want to see essentially duplicate questions for every publisher and /or journal. I think size of the publisher plays a role and the fact that its reputation is a little murky.

Comment: I don't think that a question about a single named publisher is necessarily too localized. For example, Elsevier publish a mindblowingly huge number of journals, so are relevant to almost all academics in almost all fields. If somebody has a question that is specific to Elsevier, why not just name Elsevier instead of beating around the bush.

Answer (score 14):

There are appropriate resources for public "shaming." People can be directed to those sites as warranted.

Comment: Like http://retractionwatch.com/.

Answer (score 3):

The naming procedure itself is quite subjective and is not persistent, since the publisher/person might change and the question would be out of sync with real information. A rather more interesting question issued would be asking for guidance to identify the properties of a dodgy publisher/person. At this instance, giving out examples on naming a publisher/person doing (or not) a particular action would help on explanation.