# Identifying Universities

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

I was preparing an [ethics](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ethics) question and realized that while I was carefully anonymizing the people involved, I was identifying the universities, etc.

Personally, I believe that knowing the universities and/or locale involved adds context to the situation but might serve to assist someone with 'less than altruistic intentions' in identifying the participants in the dilema.

I also know that while I've only recently joined this community, I have followed many [ethics](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ethics) questions in the past through the [Hot Network Questions](https://stackexchange.com/questions?tab=hot) sidebar from other sites. TBH, I don't recall other ethics related question(s) where scholastic institutions were named.

How should I proceed and stay on-topic while accurately describing the situation? An accurate description of the situation involves at least five universities and a couple of countries. I feel that locale is important because the ethical conundrum involves student loans.

Comment: See https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1297/929

Comment: Thanks @StrongBad. That didn't directly address my issue but it did help provide perspective.

Comment: It's a judgment call. There is no one-size-fits-all answer. Ask yourself whether an identification of the researchers involved is realistic, and if yes, whether it's worth risking anyway. There are quite a few sui-generis universities in the US alone, so there will be cases where even despite a lack of anonymity you'll want to mention the place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend sharing the relevant details without naming the schools. For example, instead of "Columbia University," you could say "a prestigious university in a large city in the US with several other nearby universities." I can't imagine any ethical quandary that is so specific it only applies to a single set of universities (and if it does, it is probably not a great fit for this site in any case).

As an aside, questions with many actors and locales are difficult to write cleanly. A lot of questions provide too many details and end up attracting few answers. Even moreso when there are awkward naming conventions ("Professor X in Country Y talked to Professors A and B...."). So, I really recommend boiling it down to the key issues and most important details.

Comment: The ethical quandary is directly regarding student loans and the avoidance of repayment. While the particular universities may not be identified, their general location (and governing laws) is a sacrosanct part of the ethical question. Maybe I'm just shortcutting my question's narrative.

Comment: including the country, or part of the world, seems reasonable (meant to include that in my example, will update).